# Trying to use a Value Converter in .Net Core to convert a long in the Model to an Object with multiple fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am making a .net core application that connects to a piece of hardware, the app is responsible for updating settings and saving them to a database. All time values on the hardware and in the database are stored as a long in seconds but the client would like the time to be editable in two separate fields, minutes and seconds and then saved back to the database and machine as a single long value.

I have attempted to write a value converter to convert from a long to a MinutesAndSecondsTime object. However, I am unsure as to how to specify the MinutesAndSecondsTime object (or if it can be done at all) as it generates a foreignkey id and can't be referred to.

The model (with additional fields removed) is:

```
public class Machine: BaseEntity
{
    public long Delay { get; set; }
    public MinutesAndSecondsTime SplitDelay { get; set; }
    public long Runtime { get; set; }
    public MinutesAndSecondsTime SplitRuntime { get; set; }
}
```

The object I am attempting to convert these values to is as follows:

```
public class MinutesAndSecondsTime
{
    public MinutesAndSecondsTime(long time)
    {
        Minutes = time / 60;
        Seconds = time % 60;
    }

    public long Minutes { get; set; }
    public long Seconds { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a TimeConverter class which is supposed to handle the conversion:

```
public class TimeConverter : ValueConverter<long, MinuteSecondTime>
{
    public TimeConverter(ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = null) : 
        base(convertToProviderExpression, convertFromProviderExpression, 
        mappingHints)
    { }

    private static Expression<Func<long, MinuteSecondTime>> convertToProviderExpression = x => ToTimeObject(x);
    private static Expression<Func<MinuteSecondTime, long>> convertFromProviderExpression = x => ToTimeLong(x);

    private static MinuteSecondTime ToTimeObject(long time)
    {
        return new MinuteSecondTime(time);
    }

    private static long ToTimeLong(MinuteSecondTime time)
    {
        return time.Minutes * 60 + time.Seconds;
    }
}
```

And in the ApplicationDbContext this is applied in the OnModelCreating function:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var entity = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "TestApp.Machine").First();
    var delayProperty = entity.GetProperties().Where(y => y.Name == "Delay").First();
    var runtimeProperty = entity.GetProperties().Where(y => y.Name == "Runtime").First();

    delayProperty.SetValueConverter(new TimeConverter());
    runtimeProperty.SetValueConverter(new TimeConverter());
}
```

I currently get:

System.ArgumentException: 'Converter for model type 'MinuteSecondTime' cannot be used for 'Article.Delay' because its type is 'long'.'

When trying to add the converter to the field in OnModelCreating. From what I can tell value conversion appears to only accept a single field. Is there a way around this or an alternative solution?

Comment: Shouldn't your TimeConverter be implemented as `TimeConverter: ValueConverter<MinuteSecondTime, long>`? Since long is the Provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand that you are trying to do is have a long data type in the database but that is converted into `MinutesAndSecondsTime`.

I would change the your Machine model to look like this:

```
public class Machine
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Column(TypeName = "integer")]
  public MinutesAndSecondsTime Delay { get; set; }

  [Column(TypeName = "integer")]
  public MinutesAndSecondsTime Runtime { get; set; }
}
```

You can change type to `int` or `bigint` depending on the Database Provider you are using. I used SQLite.

The `ValueConverter` should be implemented like so:

```
public class TimeConverter : ValueConverter<MinutesAndSecondsTime, long>
{
    public TimeConverter(ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = null) :
        base(convertToProviderExpression, convertFromProviderExpression,
        mappingHints)
    { }

    private static Expression<Func<MinutesAndSecondsTime, long>> convertToProviderExpression = x => ToTimeLong(x);

    private static Expression<Func<long, MinutesAndSecondsTime>> convertFromProviderExpression = x => ToTimeObject(x);

    private static MinutesAndSecondsTime ToTimeObject(long time)
    {
        return new MinutesAndSecondsTime(time);
    }

    private static long ToTimeLong(MinutesAndSecondsTime time)
    {
        return time.Minutes * 60 + time.Seconds;
    }
}
```

Notice I switched the type parameters to `TimeConverter`. You can learn more about ValueConverter [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)

Then you can implement the `OnModelCreating` like so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
       modelBuilder
            .Entity<Machine>()
            .Property(e => e.Delay)
            .HasConversion(new TimeConverter());

        modelBuilder
           .Entity<Machine>()
           .Property(e => e.Runtime)
           .HasConversion(new TimeConverter());
}
```

Then when insert values into the database using `MinutesAndSecondsTime` object, like so:

```
db.Machines.Add(new Machine()
{
  Delay = new MinutesAndSecondsTime(10000)
});
db.SaveChanges();
```